# Exclude certain disk in dd command script for disk erasure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aix, ksh

```
 for disk in $(lspv | awk '{print $1}') ; do
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/${disk} bs=1024 count=$(bootinfo -s ${disk})
   echo $disk wiped
done
```

How do i exclude certain disks like hdisk0,hdisk1 and hdisk3?

Regards,
Adel

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be:

```
for disk in $(lspv | awk '{print $1}') ; do
   case "$disk" in
      hdisk0|hdisk1|hdisk3)
          continue
          ;;
   *)
       dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/${disk} bs=1024 count=$(bootinfo -s ${disk})
       echo $disk wiped
       ;;
   esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, either explicitly list the disks you want to erase in your command, or add some kind of filter to your command.

Perhaps something like `lspv | awk '!/regex/ {print $1}'`

Comment: the above command doesnt remove disk needed,it list all disks.

Comment: Right, If it wasn't obvious, you would need to adapt the `regex` with an actual regular expression that excludes the drives you want to exclude.